# CodeIgniter 4 Model and the Query Builder class for complex queries

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Which is the best method to use for the CodeIgniter 4 among the Model and the Query Builder class? What are the limitations of the CodeIgniter 4 Model and the Query Builder?

I searched a lot about this question. But I did not get any clear answer. For complex queries currently, I am using the Query Builder class. But I want to know what is the best method among the CodeIgniter 4 Model and the Query Builder class. Your answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Read https://learncodeigniter.net/codeigniter-tutorials/codeigniter-4-models-vs-query-builder/

Answer (score 2):

### It depends on your needs and preferences.

**Model class -** This is used by extending the `base Model class`, and you can add your own functions/methods. It is not as flexible as the `Query Builder`, and it only has pre-defined methods.

**Query Builder -** Easy to build complex queries. But more room for errors if didn't handle it. Ex SQL injection if you failed to validate it properly.